# Is it possible to use Entity Framework with MSDAORA provider?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, entity

I am using Visual Studio 2015 community version. I added Entity framework, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework through the nuget package manager, and this allows me to set the data source as an oracle database, but there is not an option to use .net framework data provider for ole db as the data provider when creating the ado.net entity data model. After struggling with this for quite some time.

Using the ODP.Net provider works in that when I test the connection it says it is connected, but I can't actually retrieve any information about the database. The closest thing I've found online to what I am looking for is [this](https://csharp.today/entity-framework-6-database-first-with-oracle/) article.